# Multiple condition count formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula which states that I want to count how many 4&5s are in column B and divide them by the total count of Column B for each of the separate countries.

I used an IF statement and also COUNTIFs but I cannot quite figure it out.

In the picture you can see the table with the formulas tried next to the cell. Note that I hid a lot of rows so not everything is visible.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BSyD.png]

code that works without checking the country

```
   =(COUNTIF(Table135[[#All];[B]]; "5") +
    COUNTIF(Table135[[#All];[B]];"4")) /
    COUNTIF(Table135[B];"<>6")
```

code with country statement included

```
= (COUNTIFS(Table135[[#All];[Country]]; "=H102:H104"; Table135[[#All];[B]];
    (COUNTIF(Table135[[#All];[B]]; "5") +
    COUNTIF(Table135[[#All];[B]];"4")) /
    COUNTIF(Table135[B];"<>6")))
```

Comment: There's no picture, but it's better to post data instead of picture using markdown table.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for Belgium it'd be `(0+0)/3` and UK `(0+2)/2`? Or is the total count not limited to one country?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use a single-cell formula and format cells with "%":

```
=LET(t;Table135;ac;TAKE(t;;1);c;UNIQUE(ac);HSTACK(c;COUNTIFS(ac;"="&c;DROP(t;;1);">=4")/COUNTIF(ac;"="&c)))
```

The table should be exactly as you depicted (two columns).

Or you can refer columns separately if Score isn't directly after Country:

```
=LET(ac;Table135[Country];c;UNIQUE(ac);HSTACK(c;COUNTIFS(ac;"="&c;Table135[Score];">=4")/COUNTIF(ac;"="&c)))
```

Comment: Did the solution help?